# smoothly decaying function with compact support

Tags: calculus

Is there any closed form function smooth in [0,1] and such that:

f(0) = 0; f(1-x) = 1 - f(x) for x in [0,1]
f'(0) = f"(0) = f'(1) = f"(1) = 0

Not relevant what it does out of [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)={1\over 2}-g(1-2x)$$ where $g(t)$ is an odd function on $[-1,1].$  Then the second assumption holds. The other assumptions are satisfied if $g(1)={1\over 2}$ and $g'(1)=g''(1)=0.$ Let $$g(t) =at+bt^3+ct^5$$ Then $$\displaylines{g(1)=a+b+c\\ g'(1)=a+3b+5c\\ g''(1)=6b+20c}$$ Now we can solve for $a,$ $b$ and $c$ to get $g(1)={1\over 2},$ $g'(1)=g''(1)=0.$ The system is solvable as the vectors $(1,1,1),$ $(1,3,5)$ and $(0,6,20)$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Take$$f(x)=\frac{1+P(2x-1)}2$$where $P$ is an odd polynomial such that $P(1)=1$ and $P'(1)=P''(1)=0,$ the simplest one being$$P(x)=\frac{15x-10x^3+3x^5}8.$$

Comment: I swear I didn't read Ryszard Szwarc's answer before finding mine.

Comment: Thank you, so simple...